# Show zero in decimal places (XML Schema)

Tags: xml, xsd

I am super new to XML.Please correct me if I am wrong. In this XML Schema, I am trying to show 2 decimal places including zeros. The below is the closest one that I can get. But it does not work. The ultimate goal is to export a number from Excel to XML and get 2 decimal places.

Example --> If we have 12345 in Excel, I want to show 12345.00 in XML after exporting it.

After reading so many websites, I still have not yet found the answer. I would really appreciate if you could help. Thank you.

```
<xs:simpleType name="TwoDecimal" id="TwoDecimal">
 <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
  <xs:fractionDigits fixed="true" value="2" />
   <xs:pattern value="\d+\.\d{2}" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: You cannot "show" the value `12345.00` instead of `12345`. XSD only _validates_ the number given. You probably want to use the function [format-number()](https://www.altova.com/xpath-xquery-reference/fn-format-number) in XSLT (which transforms one XML to another).

Comment: @zx485 Thanks. You gave the the direction. I will have a look.

Comment: Note also that there's a difference between fractionDigits and pattern. The fractionDigits facet constrains the value space: fractionDigits=2 effectively means the value must be an integer multiple of 0.01, but it doesn't care how it is written - for example 23.4500 and 23.0 would both be fine. The pattern facet constrains the lexical space - it's concerned with how the value is written. But neither (directly) affects the way values are serialized; they're only used on input, not on output.